# Xero Partner API Oauth certificates issue when trying to obtain tokens ( Linux / Perl )

Tags: linux, perl, xero-api

I am attempting to complete our integration with the Xero Partner API and am having some trouble with the Oauth process for obtaining tokens. We didn't have a problem with this using the public API but with the partner API that requires a client certificate, we keep getting an error "Can't connect to api-partner.network.xero.com:443".

We handle this oauth part from an authorization server, an Apache/Linux Server running perl code.
The rest of the calls are made from our main IIS server and we have no problems there.

What's puzzling is that according to the docs we don't even need the client certificate for the oauth calls. 
http://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/partner-applications/

However, at first we received error messages saying otherwise ("certificate verify failed") and we guessed that we do need the client certificate even at this stage. So we tried to install and use all certificate variations but still we cant connect.

Can anyone confirm that oauth calls require the client certificate and if so elaborate on what is needed in order to complete the Oauth step on an apache/linux server? What certificates are needed and how do we install them?

Thank you very much,
Guy.

Comment: Have you talked to their customer service?

Comment: Posted on the developers forum but no replies yet ..

Answer (score 1):

Xero provides 3 types of application integration approaches that all use the [OAuth (v1.0a)](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/)  protocol to authenticate 3rd party applications.

Using the 'private' and 'partner' applications will make use of a cert while using the public application will not. Private applications are appropriate when you just wish to establish an integration point between your application and your Xero data. Public applications are appropriate when you wish to obtain access to your user's Xero data and require them to authorise this ( for 30 minutes ). Partner applications are an evolution of the Public applications and require Xero approval but operate similarly except that the user doesn't need to re-authenticate every 30 minutes to provide you with access to their data.

You should first ensure you are familiar with the Xero docs and particularly the [Getting Started Guide](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/getting-started-guide/) .

With regards to perl there is a Net::Xero module on CPAN. I used this to inform my own CCP:Xero module which is available on Github at https://github.com/pscott-au/CCP-Xero